# GoogleSheet IMPORTHTML Link in Button

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I use a googlesheet and IMPORTHTML to get the content of this page :

https://meteor.dsac.fr/documentation.php

It works fine, except the last column : the return value is "Consulter", however I would like to get the link instead (eg: https://meteor.dsac.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/meteor-externe/#communication/18280)

Is there a way to do that with that function?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current stage, `IMPORTHTML` cannot retrieve the attribute of the tag. So, for example, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTHTML("https://meteor.dsac.fr/documentation.php","table",1),{"";IMPORTXML("https://meteor.dsac.fr/documentation.php","//td[4]/a/@href")}},"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col5")
```

- In this sample formula, in order to retrieve the URLs instead of the value of "Consulter", `IMPORTXML` is used.

#### Testing:

When this formula is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339)
- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: Thank you for that.
Actually this formula returns me an error - I tried to figure out what the problem was but i did not find...

Comment: @Fanch Ooh Thank you for replying. About `Thank you for that. Actually this formula returns me an error - I tried to figure out what the problem was but i did not find...`, I have to apologize for this. When I tested my proposed formula, no error occurs. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: I found it, ; instead of ,